# How to check gradle build variant (debug or release) from dependency in Android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

It is possible to set a variable in `debug` or `release` of `buildTypes` of app module. This doc has explained how to do that, Android: [Managing different server URL for development and release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30758160/513413).

However, my problem is different slightly. I have Project_A which is dependency to my App_Module. A class on my Project_A needs to know this build is Debug or Release. I created a variable in `buildTypes` based on what above doc's said (in App_Module). However, the variable seems is not visible to this dependency (Project_A).

I have following code in a class of Project_A:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
{
    MyConstants.URL_BASE = "https://my.debug.com";
}
else
{
    MyConstants.URL_BASE = "https://my.release.com";     
}
```

When I check the package of `BuildConfig`, the package belongs to Project_A (and there is no sign of App_Module in dropdown list of auto import packages). So what is your recommendation? How can I check build variant from dependency?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17201265/1852441 Did u try this ?

Comment: @JaswanthManigundan, yes, both (your link and mine) are similar answers that are using `debug` and `release` of `buildTypes`. Thanks.

Comment: Your Module A can have a debug and release buildtype as well. If module A change de build variant then the other modules will change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following solution for my problem. I defined `Debug` variable in Application class of Project_A:

```
 // Placeholder for the BuildConfig.DEBUG flag. Should be overwritten by the final application class
 // with the correct value based on build variant (debug/release).
 public static boolean       DEBUG = true;
```

Then, I'm set it from Application class of App_Module.

```
// Setup the debug flag
PassengerLibApplication.DEBUG = BuildConfig.DEBUG;
```

Therefore, my above code will be changed to

```
if (Project_A_Application.DEBUG)
{
    MyConstants.URL_BASE = "https://my.debug.com";
}
else
{
    MyConstants.URL_BASE = "https://my.release.com";     
}
```