# Define running environment (SIT/UAT/prod) of an app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, config.json

I have an application used to call web services where base URL are different for different environment (dev/SIT/UAT/preProd/prod etc...)
So I have decided to add base URL on Config.json file.

```
"env:development": { 
"BASE_URL" : "https://xxxx/api/" 
}, 
"env:SIT": { 
"BASE_URL" : "http://1yyyy/api/" 
},
"env:UAT": { 
"BASE_URL" : "http://1yyyy/api/" 
},
"env:production": { 
"BASE_URL" : "ccccc" 
},
```

Now My question is... 
If I want to make a build for SIT or UAT or Production, How that app will take appropriate base url.
How to define that I am running my app on development SIT, UAT or production?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39116533/9928916 you can get an idea.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define your own environments. There are predefined ones that are used on compile of your app. There is only 1 environment in the compiled app.

You can find which environment does what in the [documentation of Appcelerator](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=35620077)

Basically, `development` is for simulators, `test` for devices and `production` if you compile ad-hoc or for app store.

If you want different URL's for different situations you will need to define them in the `global` part for example and make logic yourself inside the app to pick the right URL's.

Comment: Thanks Rene, Yes I have that logic which will pick that URL depending on situation. But I am looking for any predefine process that Appcelerator provides to do the same which may reduce some code.

Comment: it is not possible to customise config.json like that. Maybe you can use grunt (or similar) to adjust the file for you