# How to Change hard coded url constants for different environments(dev and prod) in Android?

Tags: java, android, deployment, production-environment

I am currently on an Android project where I have to switch the project on two environments(Prod and dev).

In the current scenario I am hardcoding a base url for prod environment, build the project and generate apk. When it comes to dev also hardcoding the corresponding url for dev environment. This becomes difficult as each time we need to switch the environment, we need to make code changes(changing the url) and rebuild the entire code. 
I found out a similar suggestion in this link [clickhere](https://qualitycoding.org/production-url/)

But I am not clear on how to achieve this. Please help with your suggestions.

Comment: Provide a url edit text in your app and whatever url is entered use that as base url or keepa radio button to switch between the development and production environment

Comment: [use product flavor in gradle.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: @VivekMishra Actually in this scenario there is no facility to add an extra field.

Comment: @HardikVasani It is not about building two different apk's. I need to place the url dynamically when it comes to dev and prod enironment.

Comment: Possible duplicate : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995057/how-do-you-manage-multiple-environments-while-developing-android-apps

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using BuildConfig.DEBUG. This will return true if you're running a debug version.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // debug version
 } else {
  // release version
}
```